# Anki-compatible app for ios or mac, which notifies me when reviews are due

Tags: ios, macos, anki

Can someone suggest me good anki app for IOS or Mac. Specifically I'm trying to find one that able to send notifications by scheduler. I'm quite lazy and don't want to open the app every day by myself.

I want the app to remind me that my Anki list is not done today.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found what I was looking for. The app called CleverDeck - it's free for 100 cards and has configurable notifications.

Comment: Is it really compatible with Anki? Can you sync from it to Ankiweb, and back?

Answer (score 0):

[AnkiMobile](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ankimobile-flashcards/id373493387) is the only official Anki application for iOS.

It has notifications, as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.ankimobile.net/preferences.html#notifications):

> When enabled, Anki will display an alert at the selected time of day, reminding you to study and telling you how many reviews are waiting.